# Time Slots for a schedule between two Datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, scheduling

If found a lot of post on how to do an hourly time slot for a schedule between two date but in my case the two dates are datetimes and they don't start at 00 minutes.
Here an example.

```
Start date = 2023-04-20 06:30:00
End date   = 2023-04-20 14:30:00
```

I would like to have a output that look like this

```
Hour  Start               End
6     2023-04-20 06:30:00 2023-04-20 07:00:00 -- ** don't start at 6:00 **
7     2023-04-20 07:00:00 2023-04-20 08:00:00
...
13    2023-04-20 13:00:00 2023-04-20 14:00:00
14    2023-04-20 14:00:00 2023-04-20 14:30:00 -- ** don't end at 15:00 **
```

Comment: What exactly is it you are asking here? What is the difficulty you are having solving the problem? What were your attempts? Why didn't they work or what about the content you read didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a generic way to return a sequence of numbers. In SQL Server 2022 (and Azure SQL Database), I like to use [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/generate-series-to-build-a-set/), but on older versions (2008+) you can substitute with something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGenerateSeries
(@start int, @stop int)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   (
     WITH n(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0)) n(n)),
      i1024(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM n a, n b, n c, n d, n e)      
     SELECT TOP (@stop - @start + 1) value = ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (ORDER BY @@TRANCOUNT) + @start - 1 FROM i1024 ORDER BY value
   );
```

Or this variation, that is even more efficient, but only for SQL Server 2016+:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGenerateSeries
(@start int,@stop  int)
 RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
 AS
   RETURN
   (
     SELECT TOP (@stop - @start + 1) value = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (ORDER BY @@SPID) + @start - 1
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',', @stop - @start), ',')
     ORDER BY value
   );
```

> `*` *If `@stop - start` might be `> 4000`, change `REPLICATE(',',` to `REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), ','),` to avoid truncation.*

With either function in place, you can then do this. We first calculate how many hours pass between start and end, and also *round* the start time down. Then we can just use `CASE` expressions to add an hour to the rounded value, or only include the *real* start or end value if we're at the beginning or end of the range.

```
DECLARE @start smalldatetime = '20230420 06:30:00',
        @stop  smalldatetime = '20230420 14:30:00';

DECLARE @diff int = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @start, @stop),
  @roundstart smalldatetime = DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, @start), @start);

SELECT [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR, [Start]), *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT [Start] = CASE value WHEN 0 THEN @start 
                   ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, value, @roundstart) END,
           [End]   = CASE value WHEN @diff THEN @stop 
                   ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, value + 1, @roundstart) END  
    FROM dbo.fnGenerateSeries(0, @diff)
  ) AS x;
```

- Working example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fUYjQ5IB)

When you get to SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL Database, and are on the right compatibility level, you can ditch the custom function and just replace `dbo.fnGenerateSeries(` with `GENERATE_SERIES(`.

Comment: Nice trick this! A small adjustment me thinks, it should be: REPLICATE(CAST(',' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), otherwise it will get cutoff after 8000 characters

Comment: @siggemannen I didn't bother mentioning that (and I would use `varchar` since there's no need to double the size), because it would mean you need a range spanning 4,001 hours. The fiddle didn't use this approach intentionally to be more compatible with broad versions.

Comment: Thanks Aaron this is exactly what I was looking for.  So elegant and simple, i love it.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty solution, I know. Hope, someone can write it better

```
DECLARE @InStartDate SMALLDATETIME='2023-04-20 06:30:00';
DECLARE @InStopDate SMALLDATETIME='2023-04-20 14:30:00';

WITH INTERVAL AS
(
    SELECT @InStartDate AS StartDate,DATEADD(MI,30,@InStartDate)AS EndDate
      UNION ALL
    SELECT I.EndDate,DATEADD(MI,60,I.EndDate)
    FROM INTERVAL AS I
    WHERE I.EndDate<DATEADD(MI,-30,@InStopDate)
)
SELECT I.StartDate,I.EndDate
FROM INTERVAL AS I
UNION ALL
 --last interval 30 min
SELECT MAX(F.EndDate),DATEADD(MI,30,MAX(F.EndDate))
FROM INTERVAL AS F
```

Comment: This works fine too, just note the assumptions about start/stop values landing precisely on `:30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with startEnd as
(select cast('2023-04-20 06:30:00' as datetime) as StartDate,cast('2023-04-20 14:30:00' as datetime) as EndDate)
,cte as
(
    SELECT datepart(hour,'2023-04-20 06:30:00') "Hour",StartDate,dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,StartDate)+1,0) endDt,EndDate from startEnd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  "Hour"+1,dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,StartDate)+1,0) StartDate, dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,endDt)+1,0)endDt,EndDate FROM cte WHERE "Hour"+1<=datepart(hour,EndDate)
)
select [hour],StartDate,(case when EndDate<endDt then EndDate else enddt end )EndDate from cte
```

| hour | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2023-04-20 06:30:00.000 | 2023-04-20 07:00:00.000 |
| 7 | 2023-04-20 07:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 08:00:00.000 |
| 8 | 2023-04-20 08:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 09:00:00.000 |
| 9 | 2023-04-20 09:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 10:00:00.000 |
| 10 | 2023-04-20 10:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 11:00:00.000 |
| 11 | 2023-04-20 11:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 12:00:00.000 |
| 12 | 2023-04-20 12:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 13:00:00.000 |
| 13 | 2023-04-20 13:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 14:00:00.000 |
| 14 | 2023-04-20 14:00:00.000 | 2023-04-20 14:30:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3LCA7N7)